# How do you make put request using content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a put request using urlsessions and the content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data. For the request url I just sample.com as a filler. Here is my code:

```
let session = URLSession.shared
            let url = URL(string: "SAMPLE.COM")!
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "PUT"
            
            request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        let requestDetails = "CarrierUserName=\(username)&BidId=\(bidId)&BidAmount=\(bidAmount)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        var done = false
        request.httpBody = requestDetails
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                
                do {
                    guard let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                        print("Could not cast JSON content as a Dictionary<String, Any>")
                        return
                    }
                    print(dictionary)
                    done = true
                } catch {
                    // Print error if something went wrong
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            repeat {
                RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))
            } while !done
            
        }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

However, everytime I make the request, the api gives me an error message. On the other hand, when using an online api tester everything works fine. The picture showing the online api tester is below.

[image]
[image]

Here is the cURL that is made by the api tester:

```
curl -i -X PUT \
   -H "token:sampleToken" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
   -d \
'CarrierUserName=ABC_675306&BidId=15&BidAmount=120' \
 'https://sample.com'
```

Comment: "the api gives me an error message" What error message? Your code seems correct and be corresponding to the curl one. (except the way you handle the async into sync code, that's not recommended).

Comment: By the way, if your request handler fails, your `repeat` never ends. Please use proper asynchronous calls. Don't use artificial waits.

Comment: For one thing, your URL should not be `let url = URL(string: "SAMPLE.COM")` but `let url = URL(string: "https://sample.com")`. The scheme is important. Your request is probably stopped by Apple Transport Security (ATS).

Comment: Yeah, it is named like ```"https://sample.com"```. How would you suggest using a proper asynchronous call?

Comment: The error message is server based, but I was wondering if there was something wrong with my code since the online api testers work

Comment: @ShamitSurana Are you sure the parameters are correct? What is the output of your body string?

Comment: The output is ```Message": "An error has occurred."``` Upon urther testing I have noticed that I can reproduce the same error in the online api tester by using a different content type (such as application/json)